# Compare two strings for duplicates and string position

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I'm writing a function that compares two arrays of letters, which are always the same length, to check for two conditions.

1. Does `array1` contain the same value as `array2` (key by key)
2. Is that same value in the same index position?

My function accomplishes this with one side effect, if `array1` contains the same letter more than once, but `array2` does not, it'll mark it as including that letter.

Here's what I have thus far:

```js
const compareWords = (array1, array2) => {
    let guess = []

    array1.forEach((letter, i) => {
        let guessMap = { letter }

        // Does the word contain the correct letter
        if (array2.includes(letter)) {
            guessMap.includes = true

            // Is the correct letter in the same position?
            if (array1[i] === array2[i]) {
                guessMap.samePos = true
            } else {
                guessMap.samePos = false
            }
        } else {
            guessMap.includes = false
            guessMap.samePos = false
        }
        guess.push(guessMap)
    })
    console.log(guess)
}
compareWords( ['M', 'O', 'M'], ['M', 'A', 'P'] )
```

## Input/Output w/Current Function:

```
compareWords( ['M', 'O', 'M'], ['M', 'A', 'P'] )

[ { letter: 'M', includes: true, samePos: true },
  { letter: 'O', includes: false, samePos: false },
  { letter: 'M', includes: true, samePos: false } ]
```

## Desired Example Input/Output

```
compareWords( ['M', 'O', 'M'], ['M', 'A', 'P'] )

[ { letter: 'M', includes: true, samePos: true },
  { letter: 'O', includes: false, samePos: false },
  { letter: 'M', includes: false, samePos: false } ]

compareWords( ['M', 'O', 'M'], ['M', 'A', 'M'] )

[ { letter: 'M', includes: true, samePos: true },
  { letter: 'O', includes: false, samePos: false },
  { letter: 'M', includes: true, samePos: true } ]

compareWords( ['M', 'O', 'M'], ['H', 'M', 'M'] )

[ { letter: 'M', includes: true, samePos: false },
  { letter: 'O', includes: false, samePos: false },
  { letter: 'M', includes: true, samePos: true } ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used examples from @protoproto and @monil-bansal to come up with the following solution.

```js
const compareWords = (word1, word2) => {
    let wordLetterCount = word2.reduce((result, letter) => {
        result[letter] = (result[letter] || 0) + 1
        return result
    }, {})

    const checkIncludes = (letter) => {
        if (word2.includes(letter) && wordLetterCount[letter] > 0) {
            wordLetterCount[letter]--
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    const guess = word1.map((letter, i) => {
        return {
            letter,
            includes: checkIncludes(letter),
            samePos: letter === word2[i]
        }
    });

    console.log(guess)
}
compareWords( ['M', 'O', 'M'], ['M', 'A', 'P'] )
compareWords( ['M', 'O', 'M'], ['M', 'A', 'M'] )
compareWords( ['M', 'O', 'M'], ['H', 'M', 'M'] )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a object from the array2. It would have the property as the elements in array2 and values as the number of times they are in array2. After that you should traverse in array1 and see if the element current element is in array2 or not and if the count>0 or not. If it is true then you would have to decrement the count of that element and you will know that the element is in the array2. 
For the sake of positions while traversing array1 you would have to traverse array2 also as you have done in the code.

```
const currentGuess = ['M', 'O', 'M']
const currentWord = ['M', 'A', 'P']
let guess = new Object()
let ans = []

currentWord.forEach((item, index) => {
    if( quess.hasOwnProperty(item) {
        guess[item]++
    }
    else{
        guess[item] = 1
    }
})

for(let index = 0; index < currentGuess.length; index++){
    if(guess.hasOwnProperty(currentGuess[index]) and 
    guess[currentGuess[index]]>0 and 
    currentGuess[index]===currentWord[index]){
        guess[currentGuess[index]]--
        console.log("{ letter: '"+currentGuess[index]+"', includes: true, 
        samePos: true },")        
    }
    else if(currentGuess[index]]>0 and 
    currentGuess[index]!=currentWord[index] ){
        console.log("{ letter: '"+currentGuess[index]+"', includes: true, 
        samePos: false},")
    }
    else{
       console.log("{ letter: '"+currentGuess[index]+"', includes: false, 
        samePos: false},")
    }


}
```

Comment: check my edit in the answer i have included the code.

Comment: This is by far the closest solution, I made some modifications to make the code more concise, which I'll update in my original question

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's not an elegant approach, but it might work for your intended purpose:

```
const compareWords = () => {
    const currentGuess = ['M', 'O', 'M', 'E', 'P']
    const currentWord = ['M', 'A', 'P', 'E', 'R']
    let guess = [];

    for (let i in currentGuess) {
        const letter = currentGuess[i];
        // Check if this letter was previously stated 
        const previousGuess = guess.find(g => g.letter === letter);
        const guessMap = { letter };
        const currentWordSubset = !!previousGuess ? currentWord.filter((v, i) => i > previousGuess.foundAt) : currentWord;
        if (currentWordSubset.includes(letter)) {
            guessMap.includes = true;
            guessMap.foundAt = currentWord.indexOf(letter);
            if (currentWord[i] === currentGuess[i]) {
                guessMap.samePos = true
            } else {
                guessMap.samePos = false
            }
        } else {
            guessMap.includes = false;
            guessMap.samePos = false;
        }
        guess.push(guessMap);
    }
    console.log(`Comparing: ${currentGuess.join('')} vs ${currentWord.join('')}`);
    guess.forEach(g => { 
        if (!!g.foundAt || g.foundAt === 0) { delete g.foundAt}
        return g; 
    })
    console.log(guess);
}

compareWords();
```

**Output**

```
Comparing: MOMEP vs MAPER
[ { letter: 'M', includes: true, samePos: true },
  { letter: 'O', includes: false, samePos: false },
  { letter: 'M', includes: false, samePos: false },
  { letter: 'E', includes: true, samePos: true },
  { letter: 'P', includes: true, samePos: false } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it shorter by use array map:

```js
const compareWords = () => {
    const currentGuess = ['M', 'O', 'M'];
    const currentWord = ['M', 'A', 'P'];
    let guess = currentGuess.map((current,index)=>{
      let obj = {};
      obj["letter"] = current;
      obj["includes"] = currentWord.includes(current);
      obj["samePos"] = current === currentWord[index];
      return obj;
    });
    console.log(guess);
}
compareWords();
```

Comment: This code is very clean, and I've used in my final solution; however, it does exactly what my original code does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check one more thing. If the array1 contains the same letter more than once then you can push it in an array at the time of first time checking and after that it will be checked in the condition if it exists in the array or not.

```
const compareWords = () => {
const currentGuess = ['M', 'O', 'M'];
const currentWord = ['M', 'A', 'P'];
let guess = [];
const exist = [];

currentGuess.forEach((letter, i) => {
    let guessMap = { letter };

    // Does the word contain the correct letter and if it is not compared previously
    if (currentWord.includes(letter) && !exist.includes(letter)) {
        guessMap.includes = true;
        exist.push(letter);

        // Is the correct letter in the same position?
        if (currentWord[i] === currentGuess[i]) {
            guessMap.samePos = true;
        } else {
            guessMap.samePos = false;
        }
    } else {
        guessMap.includes = false;
        guessMap.samePos = false;
    }
    guess.push(guessMap);
})
console.log(guess);
```

}

Comment: This solution works if the second word never includes a duplicate letter, but fails if it does. Thanks though, it led me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using `reduce`, for example:

```js
const compareWords = () => {
  const currentGuess = ['M', 'O', 'M']
  const currentWord = ['M', 'A', 'P']
  
  const result = currentGuess.reduce((result, currentGuessCharacter, currentGuessIndex) => {
    const currentWordIndexFound = currentWord.findIndex(currentWordCharacter => currentWordCharacter === currentGuessCharacter);    

    return [
      ...result,
      { 
        letter: currentGuessCharacter, 
        includes: currentWordIndexFound > -1, 
        samePos: currentGuessIndex === currentWordIndexFound 
      }
    ]
  }, []);

  console.log(result);
}

compareWords();
```